# How to receive data from Microsoft Kinect device?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, robotics

I'm wondering are their any codes or application that I can use to receive data from Kinect device.

The idea is to use the kinect to send its signals to a surface and get back range of signal data. this could be set of numbers which will change according to the light, distance and angel 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Kinect v1 or Kinect v2? If you are using Kinect v2 there are many examples included in the SDK!

Comment: it is a xbox 360 sensor. Does that mean sdk does not have samples ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with downloading the sdk from the link below (windows 8 or above is required for kinect to pc) and use their demo projects to see how to set up a program to read data in from the Kinect. It will have colour and depth cameras and you will be able to get the pixel data back and be able to use the depth feedback to tell how far away something is. As far as angle, the Kinect doesn't have a built in gyroscope so you'll have to use known points and trig to find angles.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561

Comment: just check and it is a xbox 360 v1 sensor. downloading the sdk but not sure it has demo projects